# Exceptional value:attempt to write a readonly database Centos 8 Apache webserver Python 3.6

Tags: python, django, apache, centos

Good evening. So I have following problem after correct login in django:
[Django database read-only error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQQk2.png)

- Owner of project and all files is apache
- Permissions on db.sqlite3 is -rwxrwxrwx
- Whole folder with project has permission 777

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested this issue had been solved in that way:

- echo 0 >/selinux/enforce